# count duplicate value in a tree scheme

Tags: scheme

i'm attempting to count duplicate in a tree. i'm attaching a picture for a better illustration. I'm on the wrong track i have no where to go. 
Here is what i did

```
(define (arbre-insere valeur arbre) 
  (cond ((null? arbre) (list (cons valeur 1) '() '())) 
            ((< valeur(car arbre)) 
                (list (cons  (car arbre) count) 
                      (arbre-insere valeur (cadr arbre)) 
                                       (caddr arbre))) 
            (> valeur(car arbre) (list cons ((car arbre) count) (cadr arbre) 
                  (arbre-insere valeur (caddr arbre) )))
            (else

             )
            ))][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you guys allergic to french? :D

Comment: arbre = tree,  insere=insert, valeur=value

Comment: Which convention do you use to build the tree? How does a leaf look like? And what does an internal node look like?

Comment: It's a Binary tree. A leaf in this case will an empty list and internal nodes are just all numbers from the root all the down leaves. I'm sorry if it doesn't answer your question properly :(

Comment: What does "just numbers" mean exactly?  I see (14 . 1) in your example. What does 14 mean? What does 1 mean? Are both 14 and 1 elements?

Comment: there is only one value of 14 in the tree therefore 14.1 (cons 14 1). if we insert 14 a second time it will be (14 . 2), a 3rd time (14. 3 ) and  on so on. so the right number keeps track of the number of occurrence of that element

Comment: Are the elements sorted in any way in the tree?

Comment: No, they just follow the Binary tree property (smaller on the left and larger on the right)

Comment: Not all binary trees have the property, so it is important to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch, where `...` and stuff in `<...>` is meant to be filled out by you.

```
(define leaf '())

; leaf? : tree -> boolean
;   return #t if the tree is a leaf,
;          #f otherwise
(define (leaf? tree)
  (null? leaf?))

; value : tree -> element
;   return the root element of the tree
(define (value tree) 
  ...)

; count : tree -> integer
;   return the count of the root element of tree
(define (count tree)
  ...)

; left : tree -> tree
;   return the left subtree of tree
(define (left tree)
  ...)

; right : tree -> tree 
;   return the right subtree of tree
(define (right tree)
  ...)

; make-node : value integer tree tree
;   construct tree from a value and count, 
;   left is a tree whose elements are smaller than value
;   right is a tree whose elements are greater than value
(define (make-node value count left right)
  (list left (cons value count) right))

; tree-insert : value tree -> tree
(define (tree-insert v t)
  (cond
    [(leaf? t)        (make-tree v 1 leaf leaf)]
    [(= v (value t))  (make-tree v <old-count+1> (left t) (right t))]
    [(< v (value t))  (make-tree v (make-node (value t) (count t) 
                                              (insert-tree v (left t)) r))]
    [(> v (value t))  <???>]
    [else (error 'tree-insert "an unexpected error occurred")]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. But why would you test if a tree is empty and later on test if it's a leaf (i thought a leaf is an empty list as well)